# Split an already compressed .zipx file

Tags: compression

I have an already compressed 157GiB .zipx archive that I need split into seven 20GiB files and one 17GiB file. Is there any way to split the archive after it has been compressed?

I compressed the file years ago and didn't have the foresight to split it in case I needed to have the parts separated.

It would be an inconvenience for me to have to uncompress it to it's full 338GiB size only to spend another 27 hours to compress it again, and I was hoping for some way to split it without re-compressing the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the archive uses solid compression.

If the archive does not use solid compression, you can extract a few files at a time and make the parts manually. Unfortunately, they won't be a perfect size since WinZip won't let you split a compressed archive. It's not clear how big your files are: if they are tiny, then this will be a rather difficult job; but if they are very large, then the job will be quite straightforward.

If the archive uses solid compression, many or all files are compressed in the same "block", so you have no choice but to extract everything.